# Is this a valid statement? (Basic calculus)

Tags: calculus

If a function $f$ is a continuous, strictly increasing function of $x$ when $x > 0$ and is $0$ when $x = 0$, then $f(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: This is not the right site for your question (please see http://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic )

Comment: @James Thomas Do you know the definition of increasing function? You don't even need continuity.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the assumption "strictly increasing" refers only to $x>0$. But the continuity of $f$ at $0$ comes to our help: Consider an $x>0$. Then
$$f(x)>f\left({x\over2}\right)\geq\lim_{t\to 0+} f(t)=f(0)=0\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the definition of strictly increasing function. If $f$ is strictly increasing then $f(x)>f(y)$ for $x>y$. So if $x>0$, then $f(x)>f(0)=0$.